# Regex for extracting exactly 10 digits from String

Tags: regex

I have multiple formats of strings from which I have to extract exactly 10 digit number.
I have tried the following regexes for it. But it extracts the first 10 digits from the number instead of ignoring it.

```
([0-9]{10}|[0-9\s]{12})
([[:digit:]]{10})
```

These are the formats

**Format 1**

```
KINDLY AUTH FOR FUNDS
ACC 1469007967   (Number needs to be extracted)
AMT R5 000
DD 15/5
FROM:006251
```

**Format 2**

```
KINDLY AUTH FOR FUNDS
ACC 146900796723423  **(Want to ignore this number)**
AMT R5 000
AMT R30 000
DD 15/5
FROM:006251
```

**Format 3**

```
PLEASE AUTH FUNDS
ACC NAME-PREMIER FISHING
ACC NUMBER -1186 057 378  **(the number after - sign needs to be extracted)**
CHQ NOS-7132 ,7133,7134
AMOUNTS-27 000,6500,20 000
THANKS
FROM:190708
```

**Format 4**

```
 PLEASE AUTHORISE FOR FUNDS ON AC
 **1162792833** CHQ:104-R8856.00 AND       (The number in ** needs to be extracted)
 CHQ:105-R2772.00
 REGARDS,
```

Comment: do need to add a boundry condition.

Comment: @epascarello can you please give me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a word boundary `\b` helps. The regex becomes: `(\b([0-9]{10}|[0-9\s]{12})\b)`.

Check it here https://regex101.com/r/6Hm8PD/2

Comment: This will pass through a lot of spaces

Answer (score 1):

To match those numbers including the formats to have either 10 digits or 4 space space 3 space 3, you might use a backreference `\1` to a capturing group which will match an optional space.

Surround the pattern by word boundaries `\b` to prevent the digits being part of a larger word.

```
\b\d{4}( ?)\d{3}\1\d{3}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OMI4C1/1)

Comment: Thank you it was helpful but I@m not sure about the 4 space 3 space 3 as it may change to 3 space 4 space 3 or some different format. though bound worked. /b

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhan What is the language / tool? And is there a maximum number of spaces?

Comment: The tool I'm working on is BluePrism (RPA Tool). There can be between numbers in 3rd format

Answer (score 1):

Your expression seems to be fine, just missing a word boundary and we might want to likely modify the second compartment, just in case:

```
\b([0-9]{10}|[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{3}\s[0-9]{3})\b
```

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3aFJ5f/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

Comment: Thank you @Emma. As I commented on The fourth bird answer, I don't want to go for 4-3-3 format as it may change.